# Why are only older generation instance types available for use in EMR?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

The current generations are mostly "5" series such as `c5`, `m5` and `r5` https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ :

[image]

But when selecting instance types for EMR the latest generations available are only `3`'s from the popup:

[image]

Why is that .. and is there a way to access the newer/latest generations?

Note: I am using the "mothership"  `us-east-1`. This is the oldest and typically the most widely supported region: I would not anticipate to be seeing *severe* limitation of instance types support in that region.

Comment: What EMR release are you running?

Comment: Also what region are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the supported instance types for EMR https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-supported-instance-types.html,  there could be two factors affecting the instance type selection you are seeing.

One factor is the EMR release. The other factor is the region you are in. The documentation States some instant types may not be available in all regions. There's also a footnote regarding releases, specifying that certain you were generation instance types are only available for a given EMR release.

Also note, per John R.  below:

> us-east-2 (Ohio) and at least some other regions have the newer instance types. us-east-1 (N. Virginia) seems not to have them

Double-check those factors against your current environment to confirm instance type availability.

Comment: I should have noted the region and have done so now. It is the fundamental `us-east-1` which should not be lacking for sure on major instance families.

Comment: `us-east-2` (Ohio) and at least some other regions have the newer instance types. `us-east-1` (N. Virginia) seems not to have them.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Thx for that : it is a surprise that the mothership region lacks new instance types.  I guess they just want to re-use their capacity from ancient days. I'll switch to a different region

Comment: RodrigoM  please incorporate @JohnRotenstein comments into your answer

Comment: @javadba done. Actually it makes sense that newer instance types or only available in newer regions: it's where all the new stuff is! We moved from us-east-1 to us-west-2 to take advantage of this. Newer regions also seem more reliable. us-east-1 has had some bigger outages in the last 2 years,  and us-west-2 has had none..